# SQL Code Smells

Tags: sql

Could you please list some of the bad practices in SQL, that novice people do?

I have found the use of "WHILE loop" in scenarios which could be resolved using set operations.

Another example is inserting data only if it does not exist. This can be achieved using LEFT OUTER JOIN. Some people go for "IF"

Any other thoughts?

Edit: What I am looking for is specific scenarios (as mentioned in the question) that could be achieved using SQL without using procedural constructs

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: This should (at the least) be community wiki

Comment: Note that a "WHILE loop" isn't strictly SQL - it's a construct in some procedural extension languages.

Comment: @mkj - I agree to your point. My question is also the same. What I am looking for is specific scenarios (as mentioned in my question) that could be achieved using SQL without using procedural constructs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some I have seen:

- Using cursors instead of equivalent (and faster) set operations (joins etc).
- Dynamic SQL for everything.
- Code that is open to SQL Injection attacks.
- Full outer joins even when they are not needed.
- Huge stored procedures (hundreds/thousands of lines).
- No comments.

Comment: (n)Hibernate does outer joins by default -_-

Comment: I would consider inserting null to be a code smell for schema design. If you have to check everything for null all the time, your code can get pretty ugly and hard to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Placing ODBC or dynamic SQL calls all over the code.

Often it is better to define a data abstraction layer that provides access
to the databases.  All the SQL code can hide in that layer.
This often avoids replication of similar queries, and makes changing
data models easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

Personally for me: anything that is not a plain INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or SELECT statement

I don't like logic in SQL.

Comment: That's ironic, given that SQL is founded on predicate logic. Perhaps you should qualify this statement (Did you mean, "No cursors", or something like that?).

Comment: I guess you haven't worked with large datasets in a corporate environment then. Not that I disagree entirely, but sometimes its the best solution.

Comment: I think, logic inside SQL is inevitable when working with Reporting.

Comment: code logic is fine within SQL, I think business logic in SQL is bad...now you're going to ask for an example: Logic normally involves IF statements for example which some people try and avoid in SQL, we for instance convert Guid.Empty values {00000....} to NULL as part of our code generated SQL scripts

Comment: So you mean *procedural* code and *procedural* logic, which is not *SQL* at all?

Answer (score 1):

My biggest beef here is definitely repetitive SQL. As an example, multiple stored procedures that perform the exact same joins but different filters.

Using Views in such cases can make your database MUCH easier to look at and work with

Comment: Could you please give an example that can only be achieved using repetitive queries, if we are using Stored Proecure? [The same can be achieved without repetition when used VIEWS]

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating vendor-specific SQL, when generic SQL would do.
2. Creating tables dynamically at runtime (other than TEMPORARY tables).
3. Letting your application code have table create or super user privs.

Answer (score 0):

The question asking for a list of *SQL* smells, no answer can be
exhaustive. I will be expanding my answer as time permits and memory
serves:

## Redundant grouping

Redundant grouping is the application of the `GROUP BY` statement—and
consequently of aggregate functions—to more columns than required. It
occurs when the author starts by collecting most of or all the data that
he needs, to group it at the very end. Redundant grouping is,
therefore, *late* grouping, for the correct approach is to group early,
and only the data that needs grouping.

If a main entity (`main`) have a journal (`jrnl`) and refer to another
enity *appendage* (`apnd`), then the following query:

```
SELECT
    main    .          Id       ,
    main    .          Name     ,
    MAX(jrnl.Entry) AS Entry    ,
    MAX(jrnl.Date ) AS Date     ,
    apnd    .          Reference,
    apnd    .          Status
FROM main
JOIN jrnl ON jrnl.Parent  = main.Id 
JOIN apnd ON apnd.Id      = main.ApndId
GROUP BY main.Id, main.Name, apnd.Reference, apnd.Status
```

has redundant grouping, because the sole purpose of the `GROUP BY`
clause is to obtain the latest journal entry. It should be rewritten in
a non-redundant mannger as follows:

```
SELECT
    main.Id       ,
    main.Name     ,
    skel.Entry    ,
    jrnl.Date     ,
    apnd.Reference,
    apnd.Status
FROM
(   SELECT
        jrnl.Parent     AS MainId,
        MAX(jrnl.Entry) AS MaxEntry
    FROM main
    GROUP BY jrnl.Parent
) skel -- eton
JOIN main ON main.Id    = skel.MainId
JOIN jrnl ON jrnl.Entry = skel.MaxEntry
JOIN apnd ON apnd.Id    = main.ApndId
```

That is—we group on the narrowest dataset possible, and join the rest
afterwards, even if it means referencing the same tables!